# Using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore at build time

Tags: asp.net-core, swashbuckle

Is there any built-in way with Swashbuckle for ASP.NET Core to generate the `swagger.json` file at build or compile time (i.e. not with `dotnet run`)?

I'm starting down a path of microservices and I thought it would be nice to generate the `swagger.json` file at build time to allow other services to generate client APIs.

Comment: I have not seen any built-in way to do that, all the swashbuckle "advanded" options like DocumentFilters  are triggered at runtime, Maybe you can generate it as part of your UnitTests?

Comment: I was testing my idea of generating the swagger.json in a UnitTest, here is my code: https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/master/UnitTests/SwaggerTests.cs#L60

Comment: Is there any news about that? I had the idea that using Swashbuckle.AspnetCore 5.0 we could have the swagger.json on bin folder, I saw something looks like it during my tests with Swashbuckle.AspnetCore 5.0 Release Candidate.

Comment: You should consider accepting the answer to your question here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcorecli) to do this.

The CLI is versioned alongside the main package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, so despite at the time of writing the readme saying use version `2.1.0-beta1`, use the version that matches your use of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.